# gsl_histogram: Value being equal to an edge between two bins, to which bin will the value be assigned?

Tags: c++, c, gsl

To which bin of a gsl_histogram is a value assigned that falls exactly on the edge between two bins?
E.g. when I call `gsl_histogram_increment( h, x)`, with x being exactly 0 and the bin edges being -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4 etc. will I get an increment in the positive range(0, 0.2) or the negative range(-0.2, 0)?

EDIT: yep my ranges are uniform.

Comment: Note that `0.2` can not be represented exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your bin distribution is linear (as in your example) then this is the code that is being executed (taken from gsl-1.15/histogram/find.c):

```
  /* optimize for linear case */

#ifdef LINEAR_OPT
  {
    double u =  (x - range[0]) / (range[n] - range[0]);
    i_linear = (size_t) (u * n);
  }

  if (x >= range[i_linear] && x < range[i_linear + 1])
    {
      *i = i_linear;
      return 0;
    }
#endif
```

note the >= for the lower bin edge and the < for the upper bin edge therefore your 0.0 value should drop into the 0.0 - 0.2 bin

for a non-linear bin distribution a binary search is performed, i.e.:

```
  /* perform binary search */

  upper = n ;
  lower = 0 ;

  while (upper - lower > 1)
    {
      mid = (upper + lower) / 2 ;

      if (x >= range[mid])
        {
          lower = mid ;
        }
      else
        {
          upper = mid ;
        }
    }

  *i = lower ;
```

note the usage of the >= implies that a value falling on a bin edge will be included in the 'upper' bin of the two (same as the linear case)

maybe double check by running your example and observing what bin the value is added to

Comment: +1 for looking up the actual source, which is more authoritative than a google search :)

Answer (score 1):

`gsl_histogram_increment` [appears to use](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gslref/Updatingandaccessinghistogramelements.html) the condition `L <= x < U` for deciding whether to place value `x` in bin `(L, U)`.  So `0` would end up in `(0, 0.2)`.